# PythonでのAES復号化でエラー”Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length”

Tags: python, pycrypto

AESで暗号化された文字列を復号化すると下記エラーが発生します。

```
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

今回暗号化されている文字列は70文字なのですが、16の倍数を要求されており、上記解消する方法がわかりません。

環境
Python 3.5.1

エラーが発生しているコード（共通鍵についてはダミーを使用）

```
import os
import hashlib
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

secret_key = hashlib.sha256('ABCDEFGH'.encode('utf-8')).digest()

encrypt_data =bytes(b'BfkH%2FBcWEdwESdJVf%2FKI5nC0exQMuzow2SO%2BRnRBIXKAntEEAGzTAbghzalj5nUg')

missing_padding = len(encrypt_data) % 4
if missing_padding != 0:
　　　　encrypt_data += b'='* (4 - missing_padding)

base64_decode = base64.b64decode(encrypt_data)

iv = encrypt_data[:16]
enc = encrypt_data[16:] 
    
aes = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
decrypt_data = aes.decrypt(enc)
```

Comment: encrypt_data が base64 だとすると、% が入っているのはおかしいです。あと、base64 デコードした結果がAESの復号に使われていません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64エンコードされた結果は、数字(0～9)、英文字(a～z,A～Z)に、+と/を加えた６４種類の文字と、エンコード結果の文字数を４の倍数にするために最後に付加する=から成ります。

「今回暗号化されている文字列は７０文字」というのは、Base64エンコードされた結果の文字数は４の倍数というのに反します。
また、int32_tさんが指摘しているように%が含まれる事はありません。

そこで、%で始まる部分はパーセントエンコーディング(URLエンコーディングとも呼ばれる）されているのではないかと推測しました。

パーセントエンコーディングで、"/"は%2F、"+"は%2Bに変換されますから、エンコード前の文字列に戻すと

'BfkH%2FBcWEdwESdJVf%2FKI5nC0exQMuzow2SO%2BRnRBIXKAntEEAGzTAbghzalj5nUg'
は、
'BfkH/BcWEdwESdJVf/KI5nC0exQMuzow2SO+RnRBIXKAntEEAGzTAbghzalj5nUg'
となります。

２つの%2Fが"/"に、１つの%2Bが”＋”に書き換えられた結果、文字列の長さは６４となり、４の倍数になっています。

Base64エンコードされたデータとして以下の文字列を使ってみてください。
'BfkH/BcWEdwESdJVf/KI5nC0exQMuzow2SO+RnRBIXKAntEEAGzTAbghzalj5nUg'
コードの他の部分に誤りがなければ、うまく動くと思います。